# pointer to pointer & Arithmetic without array & dynamic list of list in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

(UPDATE)

Could we use pointer arithmetic to a "pointer to pointer" without reference to an array?

Example:

```
int val = 10;
int *b = &val; // UPDATE here:I create a pointer b now
int **a = &b;
**a = 12; //change val's value through a
int *c = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)); // UPDATE here
*(a+1) = c // Is this OK?
```

I have tried this in CLion, it compiles and seem working normally. But I kind of feel unsure about the memory leak or overwrite, etc. But if we could do this, then, if we'd like to implement a linked list, could we just define a pointer to a pointer to the `Node`?

```
struct Node{
  int val;
  Node *next;
}
```

Then, if we define Node ** pathList, we could use the pointer arithmetic to get a list of path, each of which contains a list of Node?

```
Node **pathList;
Node *firstPath = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
pathList = &firstPath;
...//add new Node to firstPath..
Node *secondPath = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
*(pathList+1) = secondPath;// IS THIS LEAGLE?
```

Comment: The first 3 lines in your first example invoke undefined behavior, `a` isn't initialized when you dereference it.

Comment: I have updated the examples as @StoryTeller mentioned.

Comment: Your claim that this `**(a+1) = &c // Is this OK?` compiled is quite dubious. It is *certainly* not correct, both syntactically and semantically.

Comment: I think you're running into problems with `**` "a pointer *to a pointer to"* ... You are saying that the value of the variable `a`, plus one, is to be treated as "a pointer to a pointer to" something else. And I'll flatly tell you that, "no, it ain't!"  **:-)**

Comment: @EOF My fault. I'm too hurry to edit it...I had planned to write:  *(a+1) = c

Comment: By now I'd consider your question maliciously incorrect. You should *not* edit the code you've already posted. Also, your claim that this code compiled is *certainly* incorrect. `*(a+1) = c // Is this OK?` Is *still* not valid C.

Comment: @EOF :-) Sorry for my improper behaviour. Not so familiar with the rules here. Anyway, Thank you! ^ ^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
*(pathList+1) = secondPath;// IS THIS LEAGLE?
```

Yes, this would cause problem in your code . As `pathList+1` would go past the memory block you allocated. And you dereference this expression, would result in undefined behaviour.

Also regarding your example -

```
int **a;
*a = &val; // a now points to a pointer to val
```

*This is also not correct* , as `a` is *uninitialized* and dereferencing it would result into again UB.

In both the cases you need first allocate memory to the pointers and then perform your operations.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of arneyCU's answer above, you undoubtedly do not want the `**` "a pointer *to a pointer to"* semantics at all.  Instead, you probably want this:

```
int *a;
a = &val;
```

Which is read as follows:

- `a` is "a pointer to an integer."
- Assign to `a` the address of the variable, `val`.

This syntax:

```
*a = &val;
```

would be read as:

- "Assign to *the `int` that `a` points to," the address of the variable, `val`.

... and C would complain that you are assigning an *address* value to an *integer* without using a typecast to say that you know what you are doing.

Yes, the C language *does* allow you to treat any pointer as an array, e.g. `a[3]`, which computes the address of "the third element, counting from zero."  The actual memory offset would be `3 * sizeof(*a)`.  It should be emphasized that *the C language assumes that you know what you are doing!*

Answer (score 0):

I have did some research about the C memory allocation problem and found some detailed explanations for my confusions about pointers and arrays.

1. When we do pointer arithmetic, what the complier really does is to increments the address it stores by the amount sizeof(type). When we call malloc twice, the block of memory that the next malloc allocates isn't necessarily next to the last lot. So by doing

   `Node *secondPath = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));`
   `*(pathList+1) = secondPath;`

We dangerously overwrite the value stored in the address *(pathList+1);

2. Since a block of `type` located contiguously in memory
   is, by definition, an array of `type`, this brings up an
   interesting relationship between arrays and pointers.
3. We can do the following:

and then later on:

```
int *ptr;    
ptr = (*int) malloc(sizeof(int)*N)
```

where N is the number of elements that you need. After this definition you can use ptr as if it was a conventional array. For example:

ptr[i]

I learnt that, in order to use pointer arithmetic properly, we need to first allocate memories first.

:-)

Some nice references:
[Malloc](https://www.le.ac.uk/users/rjm1/cotter/page_69.htm)
[Pointers and Arrays](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse143/comp-info/c-pointers-tutorial/chapter2.html)